# Typescript Invalid left-hand operator

Tags: javascript, typescript, browser-sync

I am new to typescript and I am following tutorial [Tour of heroes from angular page](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/) In the final chapter of the tutorial when I am trying to use HTTP with the following code

Everything runs fine though I get this error from typescript compiler.

[image]

The problem is because of this error I have to refresh the browser since browsersync is not syncing because of error.

Can any body help me here?

Following is the code

> Hero.service.ts

```
import { HEROES }from './mock.heroes';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
    url: string;
    constructor(private http: Http){
        this.url = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
        this.http = http;
    }
    getHeros(): Promise<Hero[]> {
        if(!HEROES || HEROES.length == 0) {
            return this.http.get(this.url)
                .toPromise()
                .then(response => {
                    HEROES = response.json();
                });
        } else {
            let promise: Promise<Hero[]> = new Promise<Hero[]>(function(resolve, reject){
                resolve(HEROES);
            });
            return promise;
        }
    }
}
```

> mock.heroes.ts

```
import { Hero } from './hero';
export var HEROES: Hero[];
```

Answer (score 1):

you declared the HEROES of type HERO array but you assigning Json to it.

you need to cast the result

`HEROES = <HERO[]>response.json()`

i would rather suggest looping of response data and building the HERO array through it, using Object.assign  if you have any function in HERO class

Comment: Thanks abhi it helped me I looped over the json array.though response.json() returns a javascript object array and not json array, I was not able to cast it directly to Hero[]